# System.TypeLoadException in IBM.Data.DB2Types.DB2DynArray

Tags: db2

I am new to use the DB2. I have added a reference for IBM.Data.DB2 DLL. The Path of the DLL is from X86 directory and also the Local Copy is set to False. 
I am using the VisualStudio 2015 with the debug property of is set for x86.
I am able to build the project successfully, but getting following runtime error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load type 'IBM.Data.DB2Types.DB2DynArray' from assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.7.4.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'IBM.Data.DB2Types.DB2DynArray' from assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.7.4.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208'.

Let me know if anyone can help me on it or need any other details to investigate it.

Comment: Open a command-promt window, and search for db2level.exe and run it and show it's output in your question.  You might find it in "c:\Program Files\IBM\sqllib\bin\db2level.exe"

Comment: Hi 

Output: 
sql10007n message -1390 could not be retrieved. reason code: "6"

It was under "c:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\sqllib\bin\db2level.exe"

Comment: Hi

I have run the db2cwadmin.bat and then run the db2level again. But still I am facing the same issue.

It looks like the configuration issue to me as well because I have just cloned the DB2 on my local by looking to on different machine.
So I didn't install the DB2 for 9.7 I just copy pasted the directory from a different machine and doing the all other configuration changes manually.

Comment: My installed DB2 is working fine tested by using db2level.exe. and it is in  ""c:\Program Files\IBM\sqllib\bin\db2level.exe" location.
But I am not able to use that because as per my analyses the version 10 does not contain the namespace DB2DynArray. 
If I will use that, then I have to make code changes for this which I am not allowed to do.

Comment: can you please suggeted me from where I can get the DB2 .exe for 9.7 version.

Comment: Can you please suggest me URL from where I can download the V9.5 or V9.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code explicitly uses the class DB2DynArray , it looks like IBM removed that class from Db2 starting from V9.7 (i.e. DB2DynArray was available in versions up to V9.5 only).

Note that Db2-LUW V9.5 and V9.7 are no longer supported by IBM (current Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows version is V11.x).

Consider an alternate solution unless the risks of running an unsupported version are signed-off by the business.

IBM registration is required to download Db2-versions(including fixpack) from [this site](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007053).

Comment: If I will use the latest version V11 then it will not support the class DB2DynArray.
I case if I get the approval for code changes then how can I changes the code written in my application for example  

 DB2DynArray DREC = LOADDASH.GetArg(4).ToString();
                        string CTM = DREC.Extract(1, 1).ToString();
                        string MRR = DREC.Extract(2, 1).ToString();
                        string YRR = DREC.Extract(3, 1).ToString();
...........

and there are many more.

Comment: Your original question is answered by version details, so mark it as answered. Don't use comments for follow up questions, instead ask a new question, and put your code (minimum verifiable example) into the new question , and give *full details * of what the code is trying to achieve, not only the lines that reference the missing class.